# Are there any special rewards for completing Adventure Mode multiple times?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

I recently completed Adventure Mode in *Plants vs. Zombies* for the iPhone. Are there any special rewards for completing it multiple times?

I noticed that when I started Adventure Mode again I had to use three plants chosen by Crazy Dave. Are these plants chosen at random or are they tailored for each specific level?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to play through Adventure mode a second time to get the **Zombologist** achievement (or **Cryptozombologist**, depending on which platform you're on). The Yeti zombie first appears in stage 4-10 (the night fog stage) on your second playthrough, and appears randomly and infrequently afterwards.

Completing each stage a second time will also give you a small amount of money instead of the seed packets you got your first time through.

The plants Crazy Dave picks for you are randomly chosen when you start the level. You can get a new selection by restarting the level. (Confirmed by Jason in the comments, thanks!)

Tip: Neither *zombologist* nor *cryptozombologist* are real words.

Comment: The plants are randomly chosen.  Each time you restart, you get a different three.

Comment: For my version, the seeds are permanent and even if you restart you still get the same 3. Is this a glitch or is it supposed to happen?